# Width of first row of floated elements?

Tags: jquery, width, css-float, css

Say that I have a bunch of divs floated left, in a grid like fashion. These are in a container with a fixed width.

Now I'd like to know the width of the first row! so that I can compare that width with the fixed width and see if there's a lot of whitespace there, which I would like to minimize.. by setting the container width to the width of the first row of elements.

Now, the difficulty is of that when I float elements there is no concept of first or second row.. Well, I don't really need to know the first row width persé, I just need to know the nr of pixels of white, empty space that is next to the last element to the right side of the container..

See this example: http://i54.tinypic.com/256wdjn.png  (don't mind the flashy colors, just for testing)

The right side has too much white space.. I can't just calculate this before hand as the margins, border widths, image widths etc are all dynamic..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly, what you can do is loop through the nested elements and use `.offset().top` or `.position().top`. If elements `n` and `n+1` are the first elements to have different top offsets, they must be in different rows.

Then add the width of elements `0` through `n` (together with their padding, borders, and margins) to get the total width of that row.

(Oh, and don't forget to exit your loop, since you only needed to compute the first row.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't really shown us your HTML so it's hard to advise very specifically, but the only way I know of to do this is to measure how big one of the grid elements is after it's in the page and then set the container to the closest integral multiple of that so that there is no extra space in the container.

jQuery has very useful methods `.width()`, `.innerWidth()` and `.outerWidth()` for measuring depending upon what exactly you're trying to do.

If the container itself has margins or padding, then you will have to account for that in computing the desired width of the container that leaves the integral amount of space on its interior.

Comment: For some reason, jquery returns zero when I wanted to get a width of this div. (in document.ready)

Comment: You'd have to show us the HTML and code for us to help further - otherwise all we can do is offer wild guesses.  jQuery's `.width()` works on elements that are in the page and visible.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it. You really don't need to do any of that. Do you always have 4 images like that? If so you can just use `width: 25%; text-align:center;` on the elements container.

Comment: No, it can be just 1 image, 10 images, 100 images.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it works for floated child nodes but you can try to add "display:inline-block" to the container div without width and height specified. this way the container gets as narrow as possible...if that is what you're seeking for.

Comment: I have to set a width as I'm making a carousel that has to update it's scrollLeft when clicking next/prev. There are divs (pages) that are floated left, inside them are the images which are inline-blocked I believe. If I try to get the width() before setting it myself, it just returns zero.